# Script that takes a file as a param not seeing the file, gives No Such File Or Directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I have a python script that takes a file as a parameter and pushes that file to Azure Blob storage. For reference my script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os, sys

from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
from azure.storage.blob import ContentSettings

storage_account = os.getenv('AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT')
storage_container = os.getenv('AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME')
access_key = os.getenv('AZURE_ACCESS_KEY')

filename = sys.argv[1]

bbs = BlockBlobService(
    account_name = storage_account,
    account_key = access_key
)

bbs.create_blob_from_path(storage_container, filename, filename)
```

When I run the above code with the parameter `/tmp/file.txt`, which is a valid path, the only return I get it:

```
: No such file or directory.
```

If I load up the REPL and execute each line one at a time, but substituting line 8 for:

```
filename = '/tmp/file.txt'
```

then it works fine. Am I using sys.argv[] wrong somehow?

Comment: @user1241241 care to elaborate please?

Answer (score 0):

Works when I run the script with `python3 script.py /tmp/file.txt`